# PayPal adaptive - can pay via more than one currency?

Tags: paypal

Can more than one Preapproved payment agreement be setup per user?

Ie Preapproved for USD and preapproved for GBD?

Answer (score 0):

Preapproval is between an API Caller (application) and a consumer. You can create as many preapprovals as needed - each one of them will get it's own preapproval key. But that said, Preapproval is just a delegated access for the app to make a payment on behalf of the user. So the same preapproval key can be used to make payments with different currencies. Just keep in mind that when there is a currency conversion - the recipient has to pay for the currency conversion fee and possibly cross border txn fee.